# How to properly keep track of addresses using STL?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, stl

**Background**

I have a vector of objects and an index (map) into those objects by name (string).
In my case, the vector only grows (items are never deleted).

**I know not to this**

```
struct Foo { };
std::vector<Foo>            v;
std::map<std::string,Foo*>  m;   // addresses are &v[0], &v[1], etc...
```

because as I add items into `v`, the old mappings in `m` may become invalidated should `v` be realloc'ed.

**QUESTION**

If I add an extra level of abstraction via `std::unique_ptr<>`, will `m` be ok should `v` be realloc'ed?

```
struct Foo { };
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>  v;
std::map<std::string,Foo*>         m;   // addresses are v[0].get(), v[1].get(), etc...
```

I think the answer is yes, due to copy elision, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Unless you really need the items in the vector to be stored in a contiguous memory area, you might want to look at [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). Pointers to element in a deque (or iterators) will never be invalidated (unless the element is removed of course).

Comment: How about `std::map<std::string,int>` where the ints are indexes into the vector. No problems with reallocation then.

Comment: @john yes, I've considered indexing/indirection - I was just wondering if the solution above would fix the issue

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I like the `std::deque` idea - thx!

Comment: Your use of `std::` implies C++ Standard Library, not the STL.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what do you call the template-containers/algorithms part of the C++ Standard Library (already a mouthful)?

Comment: @kfmfe04: I've never found myself needing a name for particular parts of the standard beyond their section headings. It's not like I need to email them or anything!

Comment: unfortunately, 99%+ of my problems/questions in the C++ Standard Library involve the template/algorithms parts of the library, so I find STL to be a nice shorthand for what I mean, even though, technically, as you pointed out, it's not accurate. For conciseness in a title, it seems to communicate the idea well enough.  Otherwise I need to say "Containers in the C++ Standard Library" instead - more appropriate for a paper, but perhaps STL is good enough for a title on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : Yes, but it has nothing to do with [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

### Some details

In the first case, the allocated memory for the vector is a contiguous array of Foo.
As you hinted, when growing the vector, if the capacity of the current array is not big enough, a new array is allocated, and your pointers in the index are still pointing to the old addresses.

```
// let x be sizeof(Foo)

Adresses       10     10+x   10+2x
Type        [  Foo |  Foo |  Foo ]
```

Reallocation occurs

```
Adresses       30     30+x   30+2x   30+3x
Type        [  Foo |  Foo |  Foo  |  Foo ]
```

As you can see, first `Foo` object is not to be found anymore at the address 10.

#### Second approach

With your second approach, you are not storing the Foo by value in the vector, but through pointers. Assuming you allocate the memory for the pointed Foo object correctly in the free store, this object does not need to move.
When the Vector grows and need to reallocate, it will allocate a new array of (unique) pointers to your Foo objects, the address of the unique_ptr will change (your Foo** if you want), the objects remaining at the exact same address as before (Foo* is the same).

```
// let y be sizeof(Foo*)

Adresses       10     10+y   10+2y  .. 50   ..  60  ..  90          
Type        [  Foo* | Foo* | Foo* ]   [Foo]    [Foo]   [Foo]
Value       (  50     60     90   )
```

Reallocation occurs

```
Adresses       30     30+y   30+2y  30+3y   .. 50   ..  60  ..  90  ..  110          
Type        [  Foo* | Foo* | Foo*  | Foo* ]   [Foo]    [Foo]   [Foo]   [Foo]
Value       (  50     60     90      110   )
```